# write steps and numbering of equation in bold black

Tags: equations, lists

```
a)estimate \, $\alpha$

b) estimate of $\rho$

3)estimate of $X_i$
```

and numbering of equation in bold black

Comment: normally you would use `enumerate` rather than label a,b,3?? by hand, but to get a bold `a)` use `\textbf{a)}`

Comment: Why `3)` instead of `c)`?

Comment: Why the `color` tag? I would consider black the default color of text.

Comment: Please, add some more information: this is hard to understand.

Comment: I wonder about the `\,` before `$\alpha$` ...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `enumitem` which allows for customizing `itemize` and `enumerate` lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
\item estimate \, $\alpha$
\item estimate of $\rho$
\item[\textbf{3)}] estimate of $X_i$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or better, `[label=\alph*), font=\bfseries]` if one doesn't want to have bold cross-references.

Comment: Indeed, then you could also just type `\item[3)]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Jasper's answer, changing from `\textbf{3)}` to a resumed list, which will be simpler when there is really a `4)` etc. following as well later on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)},font=\bfseries]
\item estimate \, $\alpha$
\item estimate of $\rho$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},font=\bfseries,resume]
  \item estimate of $X_i$
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]